# StackOverflowException thrown in .NET MVC project with Web Api

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I created a very simple MVC 4 with Web API project in visual studio Web Developer 2010.

It tries to connect a SQL Server database and pull out the data from a table.

In the api controller, I wrote:

```
// GET api/gcurobservation/5
public IQueryable<GCUR_OBSERVATION> Get(int id)
{
    return gcurObsRepo.FindGCURObservationByLocId(id);
}
```

The repository class, method "FindGCURObservationByLocId" is defined:

```
// Query Methods
public IQueryable<GCUR_OBSERVATION> FindGCURObservationByLocId(int locId)
{
    var records = from l in db.GCUR_OBSERVATIONs
                  where l.LocationId == locId
                  orderby l.ObservationId
                  select l;

    return records;
}
```

In the debug mode, I could see each GCUR_OBSERVATION object returned from the query. So I am pretty sure the repository works OK but the controller code threw the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
```

Any tips? Thanks!

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Does GCUR_OBSERVARTION have any Foreign Key / Navigation Properties that might produce a circular reference?

Comment: Yes, GCUR_OBSERVARTION does have foreign keys with another table.But how can I find if that might produce a circular reference?

Comment: try using OData queries  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options

Comment: Have checked the foreign key integrity and didn't find any problem with it.

Comment: Can you post the definitions of GCUR_OBSERVARTION and also definition of classes on which it depends?